# How to make VisualBrush-icons in WPF stretch the same way

Tags: wpf, stretch, visualbrush, opacitymask

**What's already working:**

I want to use SVG-icons in my applications.
So I have downloaded a few icons from Material.io and converted them with Inkscape into XAML files.

The content of these files is then used in a `<VisualBrush>` as a `<Rectangle.OpacityMask>`.
By doing so I can change foreground and backfground color as I wish.
Thats important because I want to be able change icon color as, without thaving to redesign them.

The VisualBrushes and colors are in a resources dictionary in the real application, but for better explanation I copied all together in one window.

**Example code:**

```
    <Grid Background="Green" Margin="4">
                <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Width="24" Height="24" >
                    <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                        <VisualBrush Stretch="Uniform">
                            <VisualBrush.Visual>

                                <!-- from SVG (baseline-chevron_right-24px)-->

                                <Viewbox xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Stretch="Uniform">
                                    <Canvas  Width="24" Height="24">
                                        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                            <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
                                        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                        <Canvas.Resources/>
                                        <!--Unknown tag: metadata-->
                                        <!--Unknown tag: sodipodi:namedview-->
                                        <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Fill="#000000" Width="24" Height="24">
                                            <Path.Data>
                                                <PathGeometry Figures="M10 6L8.59 7.41 13.17 12l-4.58 4.59L10 18l6-6z" FillRule="NonZero"/>
                                            </Path.Data>
                                        </Path>
                                        <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" >
                                            <Path.Data >
                                                <PathGeometry Figures="M0 0h24v24H0z" FillRule="NonZero" />
                                            </Path.Data>
                                        </Path>
                                    </Canvas>
                                </Viewbox>

                                <!-- end from SVG-->

                            </VisualBrush.Visual>
                        </VisualBrush>
                    </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                </Rectangle>
            </Grid>
```

**Wat's not working:**

The icons scale in a different way as I want.

- If I use `<VisualBrush Stretch="None">`, the icons all have the same size, but they dont increase in size, when I make my rectangles bigger. Thats exactly what I expect from Stretch = "None", but not what I need.

  [image: Stretch="None"]
- If I use `<VisualBrush Stretch="Uniform">`, the icons  scale up to the rectangle size but they get too big, and vary in size. (the "chevron" is way bigger than the "export" icon).
  I think the VisualBrush is ignoring the size of the Canvas and Path, and instead using the size of **visible** part of the path.

  [image: Stretch="Uniform"]
- Other variants of stretch like Fill also dont work:

  [image]

**What I need:**

The icons should grow and shrink with rectangle size, as normal icons would do. But they should grow/shink at the same ratio.

[image: wanted behavior]

**Question:**

Is there a possible setting that gets me the desired behavior?

**Bonus:**

I want to achieve the desired functionality without reworking the ViewBox or its content, because thats autogenerated code from Inkscape.

**Full code of my testing page:**

```
<Window x:Class="Testprojekt.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Testprojekt"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" WindowStyle="None"  Width="88" Height="200" FontSize="8" >
<Grid >

    <StackPanel >
        <Label>Stretch="None"</Label>
        <!-- Rectangle size = SVG-size  , Stretch="None" -->
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Grid Background="Green" Margin="4">
                <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Width="24" Height="24" >
                    <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                        <VisualBrush Stretch="None">
                            <VisualBrush.Visual>

                                <!-- from SVG (baseline-chevron_right-24px)-->

                                <Viewbox xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Stretch="Uniform">
                                    <Canvas  Width="24" Height="24">
                                        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                            <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
                                        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                        <Canvas.Resources/>
                                        <!--Unknown tag: metadata-->
                                        <!--Unknown tag: sodipodi:namedview-->
                                        <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Fill="#000000" Width="24" Height="24">
                                            <Path.Data>
                                                <PathGeometry Figures="M10 6L8.59 7.41 13.17 12l-4.58 4.59L10 18l6-6z" FillRule="NonZero"/>
                                            </Path.Data>
                                        </Path>
                                        <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" >
                                            <Path.Data>
                                                <PathGeometry Figures="M0 0h24v24H0z" FillRule="NonZero"/>
                                            </Path.Data>
                                        </Path>
                                    </Canvas>
                                </Viewbox>

                                <!-- end from SVG-->

                            </VisualBrush.Visual>
                        </VisualBrush>
                    </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                </Rectangle>
            </Grid>

            <Grid Background="Green" Margin="4">
                <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Width="24" Height="24" >
                    <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                        <VisualBrush Stretch="None">
                            <VisualBrush.Visual>

                                <!-- from SVG (baseline-save_alt-24px)-->

                                <Viewbox xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Stretch="Uniform">
                                    <Canvas  Width="24" Height="24">
                                        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                            <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
                                        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                        <Canvas.Resources/>
                                        <!--Unknown tag: metadata-->
                                        <!--Unknown tag: sodipodi:namedview-->
                                        <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"  Fill="#000000" Width="24" Height="24">
                                            <Path.Data>
                                                <PathGeometry Figures="M19 12v7H5v-7H3v7c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2v-7h-2zm-6 .67l2.59-2.58L17 11.5l-5 5-5-5 1.41-1.41L11 12.67V3h2z" FillRule="NonZero"/>
                                            </Path.Data>
                                        </Path>
                                        <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" >
                                            <Path.Data>
                                                <PathGeometry Figures="M0 0h24v24H0z" FillRule="NonZero"/>
                                            </Path.Data>
                                        </Path>
                                    </Canvas>
                                </Viewbox>
                                <!-- end from SVG-->

                            </VisualBrush.Visual>
                        </VisualBrush>
                    </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                </Rectangle>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>

        <!-- Rectangle size > SVG-size  , Stretch="None" -->
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Grid Background="Green" Margin="4">
                <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Width="32" Height="32" >
                    <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                        <VisualBrush Stretch="None">
                            <VisualBrush.Visual>

                                <!-- from SVG (baseline-chevron_right-24px)-->

                                <Viewbox xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Stretch="Uniform">
                                    <Canvas  Width="24" Height="24">
                                        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                            <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
                                        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                        <Canvas.Resources/>
                                        <!--Unknown tag: metadata-->
                                        <!--Unknown tag: sodipodi:namedview-->
                                        <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Fill="#000000" Width="24" Height="24">
                                            <Path.Data>
                                                <PathGeometry Figures="M10 6L8.59 7.41 13.17 12l-4.58 4.59L10 18l6-6z" FillRule="NonZero"/>
                                            </Path.Data>
                                        </Path>
                                        <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" >
                                            <Path.Data>
                                                <PathGeometry Figures="M0 0h24v24H0z" FillRule="NonZero"/>
                                            </Path.Data>
                                        </Path>
                                    </Canvas>
                                </Viewbox>

                                <!-- end from SVG-->

                            </VisualBrush.Visual>
                        </VisualBrush>
                    </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                </Rectangle>
            </Grid>

            <Grid Background="Green" Margin="4">
                <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Width="32" Height="32" >
                    <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                        <VisualBrush Stretch="None">
                            <VisualBrush.Visual>

                                <!-- from SVG (baseline-save_alt-24px)-->

                                <Viewbox xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Stretch="Uniform">
                                    <Canvas  Width="24" Height="24">
                                        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                            <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
                                        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                        <Canvas.Resources/>
                                        <!--Unknown tag: metadata-->
                                        <!--Unknown tag: sodipodi:namedview-->
                                        <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"  Fill="#000000" Width="24" Height="24">
                                            <Path.Data>
                                                <PathGeometry Figures="M19 12v7H5v-7H3v7c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2v-7h-2zm-6 .67l2.59-2.58L17 11.5l-5 5-5-5 1.41-1.41L11 12.67V3h2z" FillRule="NonZero"/>
                                            </Path.Data>
                                        </Path>
                                        <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" >
                                            <Path.Data>
                                                <PathGeometry Figures="M0 0h24v24H0z" FillRule="NonZero"/>
                                            </Path.Data>
                                        </Path>
                                    </Canvas>
                                </Viewbox>
                                <!-- end from SVG-->

                            </VisualBrush.Visual>
                        </VisualBrush>
                    </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                </Rectangle>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>

        <Label>Stretch="Uniform"</Label>

        <!-- Rectangle size = SVG-size  , Stretch="Uniform" -->
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Grid Background="Green" Margin="4">
                <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Width="24" Height="24" >
                    <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                        <VisualBrush Stretch="Uniform">
                            <VisualBrush.Visual>

                                <!-- from SVG (baseline-chevron_right-24px)-->

                                <Viewbox xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Stretch="Uniform">
                                    <Canvas  Width="24" Height="24">
                                        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                            <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
                                        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                        <Canvas.Resources/>
                                        <!--Unknown tag: metadata-->
                                        <!--Unknown tag: sodipodi:namedview-->
                                        <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Fill="#000000" Width="24" Height="24">
                                            <Path.Data>
                                                <PathGeometry Figures="M10 6L8.59 7.41 13.17 12l-4.58 4.59L10 18l6-6z" FillRule="NonZero"/>
                                            </Path.Data>
                                        </Path>
                                        <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" >
                                            <Path.Data >
                                                <PathGeometry Figures="M0 0h24v24H0z" FillRule="NonZero" />
                                            </Path.Data>
                                        </Path>
                                    </Canvas>
                                </Viewbox>

                                <!-- end from SVG-->

                            </VisualBrush.Visual>
                        </VisualBrush>
                    </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                </Rectangle>
            </Grid>

            <Grid Background="Green" Margin="4">
                <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Width="24" Height="24" >
                    <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                        <VisualBrush Stretch="Uniform">
                            <VisualBrush.Visual>

                                <!-- from SVG (baseline-save_alt-24px)-->

                                <Viewbox xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Stretch="Uniform">
                                    <Canvas  Width="24" Height="24">
                                        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                            <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
                                        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                        <Canvas.Resources/>
                                        <!--Unknown tag: metadata-->
                                        <!--Unknown tag: sodipodi:namedview-->
                                        <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"  Fill="#000000" Width="24" Height="24">
                                            <Path.Data>
                                                <PathGeometry Figures="M19 12v7H5v-7H3v7c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2v-7h-2zm-6 .67l2.59-2.58L17 11.5l-5 5-5-5 1.41-1.41L11 12.67V3h2z" FillRule="NonZero"/>
                                            </Path.Data>
                                        </Path>
                                        <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
                                            <Path.Data>
                                                <PathGeometry Figures="M0 0h24v24H0z" FillRule="NonZero"/>
                                            </Path.Data>
                                        </Path>
                                    </Canvas>
                                </Viewbox>
                                <!-- end from SVG-->

                            </VisualBrush.Visual>
                        </VisualBrush>
                    </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                </Rectangle>

            </Grid>

        </StackPanel>

        <!-- Rectangle size > SVG-size  , Stretch="Uniform" -->
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Grid Background="Green" Margin="4">
                <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Width="32" Height="32" >
                    <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                        <VisualBrush Stretch="Uniform">
                            <VisualBrush.Visual>

                                <!-- from SVG (baseline-chevron_right-24px)-->

                                <Viewbox xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Stretch="Uniform">
                                    <Canvas  Width="24" Height="24">
                                        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                            <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
                                        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                        <Canvas.Resources/>
                                        <!--Unknown tag: metadata-->
                                        <!--Unknown tag: sodipodi:namedview-->
                                        <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Fill="#000000" Width="24" Height="24">
                                            <Path.Data>
                                                <PathGeometry Figures="M10 6L8.59 7.41 13.17 12l-4.58 4.59L10 18l6-6z" FillRule="NonZero"/>
                                            </Path.Data>
                                        </Path>
                                        <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" >
                                            <Path.Data >
                                                <PathGeometry Figures="M0 0h24v24H0z" FillRule="NonZero" />
                                            </Path.Data>
                                        </Path>
                                    </Canvas>
                                </Viewbox>

                                <!-- end from SVG-->

                            </VisualBrush.Visual>
                        </VisualBrush>
                    </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                </Rectangle>
            </Grid>

            <Grid Background="Green" Margin="4">
                <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Width="32" Height="32" >
                    <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                        <VisualBrush Stretch="Uniform">
                            <VisualBrush.Visual>

                                <!-- from SVG (baseline-save_alt-24px)-->

                                <Viewbox xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Stretch="Uniform">
                                    <Canvas  Width="24" Height="24">
                                        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                            <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
                                        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                        <Canvas.Resources/>
                                        <!--Unknown tag: metadata-->
                                        <!--Unknown tag: sodipodi:namedview-->
                                        <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"  Fill="#000000" Width="24" Height="24">
                                            <Path.Data>
                                                <PathGeometry Figures="M19 12v7H5v-7H3v7c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2v-7h-2zm-6 .67l2.59-2.58L17 11.5l-5 5-5-5 1.41-1.41L11 12.67V3h2z" FillRule="NonZero"/>
                                            </Path.Data>
                                        </Path>
                                        <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
                                            <Path.Data>
                                                <PathGeometry Figures="M0 0h24v24H0z" FillRule="NonZero"/>
                                            </Path.Data>
                                        </Path>
                                    </Canvas>
                                </Viewbox>
                                <!-- end from SVG-->

                            </VisualBrush.Visual>
                        </VisualBrush>
                    </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                </Rectangle>
            </Grid>

        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: use `Stretch="Fill"`?

Comment: Already tried all of the possible stretch-variants.
It gets even worse, because the icons simply get wider

Comment: ASh, thanks for you support. I added this point to my question.

Comment: What about adding a Transparent Background to the Canvas and thus make it "render" its 24x24 area? Would make sense of course only when the Paths aren't larger than the area.

Comment: Clemens, thats a good idea, `<Rectangle Width="24" Height="24" Fill="Transparent" />` does the trick.

Comment: Still not my favorite solution because I have to edit autogenerated code, but at least I have a backup plan now, if there is no other solution.

Comment: Seems its also possible to just set the Canvas Background to transparent.
Interresting :)

Comment: Sorry Clemens, I misinterpreted your "adding" as adding a child ;)

Comment: Providing Margin `Margin="5"` in uniform rectangle should be enough

       e.g `<Rectangle Fill="Blue" Width="10" Height="10" Margin="5">`

Comment: I fear that wont help. Adding a margin will make the icons look better, but not solve my problem of different icon sizes. I would also have to set the margin for different icons individually.